# Section-wise Table of Contents for Articles

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, article

Is it possible to have a section-wise *Table of Contents* in the `article` class?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, this is possible. For example with `minitoc` or with the newer package `etoc`. But please   help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` (in future ;-).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way seems to be `etoc` by your fellow user `[tag:jfbu]` here, just using the `\localtableofcontents` where appropiate

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{One}
\localtableofcontents

\subsection{First}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\section{Two}
\localtableofcontents

\clearpage
\subsection{First}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this query by a bit of search on the forum.

Using package,

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
```

with command,

```
\newcommand\MiniToC{%
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
  \startcontents
  \printcontents{}{1}{\section*{\contentsname}\vskip-3.5ex\hrulefill\vskip1ex}
  \vskip-0.5ex\noindent\hrulefill
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
```

helps me with what I want.